# How can I cast shadow on a plane with the light's color showing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shadows, shadowcatcher

How can i cast a shadow on a plane and also have a light's color on it
In the picture i linked there is shadow but no color from the cube wich is an has an emmision shader.
There is also no color casted from lights.
[image]